# When using \textbf in latex , it change the position of the value inside

Tags: latex

I am trying to display a table of my results using latex but I have some problem with the displaying: The numbers are not centered when applying bold, could you help me figure out why, below the code and what it looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}% Include the listings-package
\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{language=python} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{comment} % habilita el uso de comentarios en varias lineas (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{lipsum} %Este paquete genera texto del tipo  Lorem Ipsum. 
\usepackage{fullpage} % cambia el margen
\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for better horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{fouriernc} % Use the New Century Schoolbook font
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Models} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{POS} \\
      & {N+POS - P}  \\ % & {V+N+L-P, S} & {V+N+L-P, S, Ne}
      \midrule
    LinearSVC & 0.44 \\ %& \textbf{0.58} & \textbf{0.58}  \\
    MultinomialNb & 0.51 \\ %& 0.51 & 0.51  \\
    LogisticRegression & 0.53 \\ %& 0.51 & 0.51  \\
    RandomForestClassifier & \textbf{0.55} \\ %& 0.56 & 0.57  \\
    KNeighborsClassifier & 0.48 \\ %& 0.50 & 0.49  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

the result is like this:

[image]

As you can see 0.55 is not perfectly align with the others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the alignment you gave to the columns.

In your `\begin{tabular}{lSSS}` line, you are declaring 4 columns, even when you commented 2 of them. It is still working that way for me, but take into account that `l` is to align left, and as bold effect adds width to the letter, if you align to the left, it will still look bigger. If you want the value to be centered, I advise you to use `c` instead of S.

This is how I did it, I hope it works for you:

1. Solution using left alignment:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Models} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{POS} \\
      & {N+POS - P}  \\ % & {V+N+L-P, S} & {V+N+L-P, S, Ne}
      \midrule
    LinearSVC & 0.44 \\ %& \textbf{0.58} & \textbf{0.58}  \\
    MultinomialNb & 0.51 \\ %& 0.51 & 0.51  \\
    LogisticRegression & 0.53 \\ %& 0.51 & 0.51  \\
    RandomForestClassifier & \textbf{0.55} \\ %& 0.56 & 0.57  \\
    KNeighborsClassifier & 0.48 \\ %& 0.50 & 0.49  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And it looks like this to me:
[image]

2. Solution using center alignment

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Models} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{POS} \\
      & {N+POS - P}  \\ % & {V+N+L-P, S} & {V+N+L-P, S, Ne}
      \midrule
    LinearSVC & 0.44 \\ %& \textbf{0.58} & \textbf{0.58}  \\
    MultinomialNb & 0.51 \\ %& 0.51 & 0.51  \\
    LogisticRegression & 0.53 \\ %& 0.51 & 0.51  \\
    RandomForestClassifier & \textbf{0.55} \\ %& 0.56 & 0.57  \\
    KNeighborsClassifier & 0.48 \\ %& 0.50 & 0.49  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

Now you need to decide which one suits you better.